# Make content in divs responsive

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive, html5-audio

I have players from soundcloud fit into a custom border on my website. The players are usually responsive, but the coding that was used to keep it inside the border is blocking it. I don't want to advise people to turn their phone so the players fit, so I'm trying to make all my content responsive with codes or a plugins and keep reaching dead ends

A link to a page with the border and player can be found [here](http://www.dontcursekids.com/tunes).

On mobile when the phone is held in portrait view, the player stretches past the screen.

I changed the height and the width in the iframe_outer of the soundcloud player HTML to auto. I'm pleased to say that it made the border and the player responsive. However, the border doesn't fit the player on any screen. Also the player and border stretches when on a large screen.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height and width of `.frame_outer`

Comment: Hello I just changed the height and width to zero under frame_outer in the soundcloud tag. It didn't make it responsive but it changed the size of the border and the player. I'm trying to make the border and player respond to mobile devices.

Comment: what do you mean by it 3?

Comment: Im sorry. I hit enter before I finished the comment. I edited to finish what I was saying.

Comment: I see that there is some confusion with my response so let me clarify. I changed the height and width of the ..frame_outer as recommended.  It changed the size of the custom border and player that is in the div.  it didn't make the border and player responsive. It made it too small to see. I'm trying to make the border and player responsive to the size of the device. So when people come to my website on their phone, they don't have to turn their device to get the best experience.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `height` of your footer.

Comment: I'm afraid changing that didn't make the content or the border responsive.